# Waiting until eventListener is called to return a promise

Tags: javascript, es6-promise, fetch-api

I'm trying to return the result of a fetch call but I want to wait until my eventListener detects a change within a dynamically rendered selector list.

You'll see the fetch call written below grabbing the values from an API and rendering the list of values.  I was wondering if there is a way to prevent the `.then(resp => resp.json())` from happening until a selection is made for selectList listener.  I would ultimately like the get the value to result.then promise so that I can use that in another fetch call in the future.

[Link to codepen](https://codepen.io/jackjackpiggie/pen/yLKBGry)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Dynamic List Test</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <!-- App entry point -->
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

```
const testUrl =
  'https://hub.dummyapis.com/employee?noofRecords=10&idStarts=1001';

const result = fetch(testUrl, {
  method: 'GET',
})
  .then(resp => resp.json())
  .then(data => {
    // Create select list
    const mainEl = document.querySelector('.container');
    let selectList = document.createElement('select');
    selectList.id = 'selectorList';
    mainEl.appendChild(selectList);
    // // Prepare name list
    let nameArray = [];
    const nameList = data;
    nameArray.push(nameList);
    console.log(nameArray[0]);
    
    for (let last in nameArray[0]) {
      let surname = nameArray[0][last].lastName;
      let option = document.createElement('option');
      option.value = surname;
      option.text = surname;
      selectList.appendChild(option);
    }

    let selectorChoice = '';
    // Grab dynamic selector value
    selectList.addEventListener('change', e => {
      selectorChoice = e.target.value;
      console.log(selectorChoice);
      return selectorChoice;
    });
  })
  .then(resp => resp.json()) // I want to wait for the eventListener to be called before this happens
  .catch(error => console.log('Error:', error));

result.then(resp => {
  console.log(resp);
});
```

Result in the console

```
(10) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]0: {id: 1001, imageUrl: 'https://hub.dummyapis.com/Image?text=CA&height=120&width=120', firstName: 'Colt', lastName: 'Altenwerth', email: 'Colt.Altenwerth@dummyapis.com', …}1: {id: 1002, imageUrl: 'https://hub.dummyapis.com/Image?text=HW&height=120&width=120', firstName: 'Helena', lastName: 'Ward', email: 'Helena.Ward@dummyapis.com', …}2: {id: 1003, imageUrl: 'https://hub.dummyapis.com/Image?text=LC&height=120&width=120', firstName: 'Liliana', lastName: 'Connelly', email: 'Liliana.Connelly@dummyapis.com', …}3: {id: 1004, imageUrl: 'https://hub.dummyapis.com/Image?text=MH&height=120&width=120', firstName: 'Myah', lastName: 'Hane', email: 'Myah.Hane@dummyapis.com', …}4: {id: 1005, imageUrl: 'https://hub.dummyapis.com/Image?text=MS&height=120&width=120', firstName: 'Mauricio', lastName: 'Stracke', email: 'Mauricio.Stracke@dummyapis.com', …}5: {id: 1006, imageUrl: 'https://hub.dummyapis.com/Image?text=CS&height=120&width=120', firstName: 'Candice', lastName: 'Sipes', email: 'Candice.Sipes@dummyapis.com', …}6: {id: 1007, imageUrl: 'https://hub.dummyapis.com/Image?text=EA&height=120&width=120', firstName: 'Evangeline', lastName: 'Aufderhar', email: 'Evangeline.Aufderhar@dummyapis.com', …}7: {id: 1008, imageUrl: 'https://hub.dummyapis.com/Image?text=RR&height=120&width=120', firstName: 'Rosetta', lastName: 'Rodriguez', email: 'Rosetta.Rodriguez@dummyapis.com', …}8: {id: 1009, imageUrl: 'https://hub.dummyapis.com/Image?text=TD&height=120&width=120', firstName: 'Tina', lastName: "D'Amore", email: "Tina.D'Amore@dummyapis.com", …}9: {id: 1010, imageUrl: 'https://hub.dummyapis.com/Image?text=PS&height=120&width=120', firstName: 'Pearline', lastName: 'Sawayn', email: 'Pearline.Sawayn@dummyapis.com', …}length: 10[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
app.js:37 Error: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'json')
    at app.js:36:22
app.js:40 undefined
app.js:32 Hane
```

Comment: Why not just move the code you need to run into the event listener, or into a function you can call from inside the listener? Event listeners are asynchronous (non-blocking), so your next `.then` *should* run before the event listener is called.

Comment: But if I understand your code, You build list based on data from API. So you want wait with data parsing, before user choose list element, but you cant show list before you parse a data.
What Im missing here?

Comment: Your second comment is correct.  I want to wait till the user makes a choice from the selectList and then return the json response in order to use that in the call to result.then.

Comment: A promise for the event doesn't really make sense here. The user might change their selection multiple times, the event listener will fire multiple times, but a promise can only fulfill once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Break this into three steps.

1. Prepare: Fetch data + cache data

```
const fetchResult = fetch(...).then(response => response.json());
```

2. Build list (use id to identify records!)

```
fetchResult.then(data => {
  // Create select list
    const mainEl = document.querySelector('.container');
    let selectList = document.createElement('select');
    selectList.id = 'selectorList';
    mainEl.appendChild(selectList);

    data.forEach(employee => {
      const option = document.createElement('option');
      option.value = employee.id;
      option.text = employee.lastName;
      selectList.appendChild(option);
    });

    let selectList.addEventListener('change', e => {
      selectorChoice = parseInt(e.target.value);
      handleUserChoice(data, selectorChoice)
    });
  }
)
```

3. Handle user choice based on `id`

```
function handleUserChoice(data, id) {
    const chosenEmployee = data.find(e => e.id === id);
    
    if (choosenEmployee) {
      // ... do what you want here!
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't call `fetchResult.then` again in the `handleUserChoice` function. Just pass in the`data` as another parameter.

Comment: mborecki and @Bergi, this seems very close.  Written very cleanly.  Although I did try this and you'll notice that the selectorChoice that was logged in the event listener is returning the id, when I log the choice made in the const for chosenEmployee, it says 'undefined' in the console.  Here's a link to the updated codepen to test https://codepen.io/jackjackpiggie/pen/yLKBGry

Comment: @Bergi it depents if you want handleUserChoice to be pure, or you use it as easy access point. But maybe in this example it should be pure.
Edited

Comment: Not just that, I just would want to handle the promise (including errors from it) only once

Comment: @JackJack if `employee.id` is a number, not a string, you'll need to use `selectorChoice = parseInt(e.target.value)` so that it can be found with `===` in the array

Comment: @JackJack - in API `id` is a `number` so you need `parseInt`.

Comment: I passed the selectorChoice in the eventListener as a number - Number(selectorChoice) then called in the handleUserChoice as chosenEmployee.id and that worked.  It doesn't need to be pure, just a simple user choice so I'll stick with this option and update from Number to parseInt.  Thank you both!